# How to make a Nginx rewrite rule for /test show /test.html

Tags: nginx

So I have been trying to get my site working in a way where:

example.com shows example.com/index.html
example.com/test shows example.com/test.html
and so on.

So my current config file is this:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    root        /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.php;

    location / { 
        try_files $uri.html $uri $uri/ @htmlext;
    }   

    location ~ \.html$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location @htmlext {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.html last;
    } 

    error_page 404 /404.html;
}
```

So I was Googling all yesterday and couldn’t get it to work. So thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
server {
  listen      80;
  listen      [::]:80;
  server_name example.com;
  root        /var/www/html;
  index index.html index.php;

  location / { 
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  error_page 404 /404.html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below config gives you the following:

`curl http://example.com/test` --> output: content of test.html

`curl http://example.com/` --> output: content of index.html

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    root        /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.php;

    location /test {
        try_files $uri.html $uri $uri/;
    }
   
    location / { 
        try_files $uri.html $uri $uri/;
    }   

    location ~ \.html$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

  

    error_page 404 /404.html;
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of "@htmltext;" ?

Comment: There is no point to have separate `@htmlext` location, because the `try_files` already includes `.html` suffix. There isn't a need for duplicate `location /test` block either.

Comment: Yeah of course not. But i wanted to minimize my configuration changes. Next time i will cut off this block and explain it in the answer.

Comment: The answer still has `@htmlext` in the `try_files`. That is not needed.